# SQL Looking up prior record information

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, runtime

Here is my situation.  I have a series of claims for a person.  We occasionally get a duplicate claim which is given a DUP error code and and denied with zero dollar amount.  What I am trying to do is look up the original claim units and billed amount.  If the duplicate and the original claim are the same units and billed amount I intend to ignore it (or at least label it as NOT a potential re-bill).  If the units and/or the billed amount are different, that claim will be labeled as a potential re-bill.

I've got a function that correctly finds the original claim primary key value and the base query runs in less than a second.  However, when I try to link that dataset back to the tables it crushes my run time to the point of uselessness.  What I don't understand is why does the function alone run so quickly but attempting to link it back bogs it down so much, we are talking about a dataset of 140ish claims over a year of activity.

If anyone could offer some insight or has a better way to accomplish this I would be obliged.

```
SELECT pre.*
--, st.unitsofservice as OrigUnits
--I only include the line above if the link to the servicetransaction table on the last line of the query is active

FROM
    (
    SELECT Sub.*--, 
        ,dbo.cf_DuplicateServiceSTID(sub.servicetransactionid) as PaidSvc
--the line above is the function returning the primary key value for the original claim
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT Pre.servicetransactionID, 
            st.servicedate, st.individualid, st.agencyid, st.servicecode, st.placeofserviceid, st.unitsofservice,
            dbo.sortmodifiers(st.modifiercodeid, st.modifiercodeid2, st.modifiercodeid3, st.modifiercodeid4) as Modifiers, 
            bd.billedamount,
            a.upi,
            b.name
        FROM (select pmt.servicetransactionid
                from pmtadjdetail pmt
                where substring(pmt.reasoncodes,1,5) = 'DUP') Pre
            JOIN servicetransaction st on pre.servicetransactionid = st.servicetransactionid
            join billdetail bd on st.servicetransactionid = bd.servicetransactionid
            join agency a on st.agencyid = a.agencyid
            join business b on a.businessid = b.businessid
        where st.servicedate between @StartDate and @EndDate
            and st.agencyid = iif(@AgencyID is null, st.agencyid, @AgencyID)
        ) Sub
        join individual i on sub.individualid = i.individualid
        join enrollment e on sub.individualid = e.individualid
    WHERE e.enrollmenttype <> 'p'
    ) Pre
--join servicetransaction st on pre.paidsvc = st.servicetransactionid
--If I remove the comment from the line above my run time increases to the point of uselessness
```

Comment: It probably makes no difference, but I really don't like the double use of the same alias (`pre`).

Comment: You want to join on the result of a function, and the parameter of that function is itself the result of a sub query, the rows of which are filtered using a substring function... The optimiser is going to have a hell of a time trying to optimise this, instead it default to evaluating for every record in the sub lookups. You should flatten this query, or re-write it the other way around. This is hard to do ad-hoc in a forum like this without access to the actual data tables.

Comment: I have worked around this by creating a table valued function then looking up the values I need from that function.  i.e. something like

(SELECT Billed FROM cf_OriginalClaimInfo(sub3.paidsvc)) as OrigBilled